# Is there anyway of having handwriting functionality in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, actionscript, mxml

I am doing a flex application, I would like to include a box where the user can freely draw in the box, like a html canvas type thing but in my flex project. Is there any way of implementing this?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, use graphics. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html i've seen a component a long time ago, you may have to research in google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; [this site](http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a67/Create-a-Simple-Drawing-Pad.html) has a simple example that should help you.